# MTP Connection: Unable to mount Samsung Android error many times in a minute!

Tags: usb, android, samsung, mtp

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my PC and I'm trying to connect my Samsung S6 device to this Ubuntu with USB on MTP Connection. I always get this popping up:

> unable to mount Samsung Android

I can't even copy even an audio track. I'm developing Android apps and need to test on my device but I cannot  get full connection between adb and my phone. I see my device name on the list but the same message pops up every 30 seconds.

[image]

I just took a screenshot. The shadows mean there are many  instances of the same dialog under that! And it already opened many empty folders as you can see. This happened in just 1 or 2 mins.

**What I have tried**

- I added attr to `51-android.rules` and `69-libmtp.rules` with `lsusb` results
- installed libmtp-1.1.12 , gmtp , mtp-tools, go-mtpfs , gvfs , mtpfs
- tried on both usb2.0 and usb3.0 port
- tried with debug enabled and disabled
- already selected MTP Connection type in USB Configuration under the Developer Options Menu in Android

Comment: Sometimes stray downvotes fly around, but it's best not to take them personally. Let's try to keep our own contributions to this site as constructive, friendly, and helpful as possible!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "troubleshooting many times in a minute". (Maybe I don't understand your usage of "troubleshooting".) Would it be possible for you to clarify what you mean? Are you seeing any specific messages or errors on your screen?

Comment: i just added a screen shot. it may helps to solve this problem :/

Comment: Have you updated /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules ?

Comment: When you say "Troubleshout" do you mean "Error Message"? To many of us it sounds like "troubleshooting" which has a completely different meaning.

Comment: yes i added attr to 51-android.rules and 69-libmtp.rules with "lsusb" results

Comment: and i also changed title of this question i hope its better than before and yes my english level is not good against urs. i really hate this problem and i tried tons of answer in this q/a ubuntu forum about mtp connection problems

Comment: Have you tried using a different cable? I had a similar issue with my Android mounting and unmounting over and over, and it turned out to be a faulty cable.

Comment: @SuperSluether idk i have to buy new cable to connect my device to ubuntu? but it works very well in windows 8.1. i saw 1-2 answer in this forum about usb 3.0 and 2.0 i tried both of them i have 1x usb3 and 2x usb2 port on my pc but no change :(

Comment: I'm not saying you NEED to buy a new cable, I'm just saying make sure the cable works. If it works in Windows, then the cable is fine.

Comment: do someone advice me any valid solution not in my solution list :/ this problem is rly annoying me

Answer (score 12):

My Galaxy S4 will do the same thing on a 3.0 USB port. Try using a 2.0 USB port if you have one. You might also try a different USB cord. It shouldn’t make a difference, but it does. I got mine to work with a 3.0 port by swapping out cords until I found one that did the job.

Comment: check my solution list.i already tried usb2.0 and 3.0 ports on my laptop :/ i have 2x usb2 and 1x usb3 port and i tried on all ports but still same message pops up "unable to mount samsung android"

Comment: Changing cord did the tricky for me!

Comment: I found a simlar situation with a Samsung tablet which requires its own cable to charge properly. I looked into it and have summarized my findings in [this Android.se answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/128832/86635).

Comment: Dont think it need's it own cable but it is clear not all usb cables are the same. some seem to charge only!

Comment: So... I've had this problem with a new Samsung A13 4G phone and Mate 20.04.  The solution was to use a slower USB port.  My `dmesg` output gives:  `usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[ 1344.231791] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 1344.440183] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 1344.647688] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 17, error -71`  This makes me think  the faster USB port expects a response that's faster than possible with my phone.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. I'm using 16.04. I just had to install `mtpfs`. Run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install mtpfs
```

Thanks to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31324414/4190670)!

Comment: It did the job! :-)

Comment: It works here too, but strange we have to install something for just that simple task. thx

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar problems - the phone would charge, but the computer (ubuntu 16.04) wasn't "seeing" it, i.e. it wasn't mounting.

For me, it didn't have anything to do with USB 2.0 or 3.0 or any of the MTP libraries.  It was simply the USB cable.  I've tested a bunch of different micro USB cables and have observed that with the cables that work, the pins inside the micro USB part are closer to the front than on cables that don't work.

```
———
  E
———
```

vs.

```
———
E
———
```

Answer (score 1):

Somebody broke VLC around Ubuntu 18.04.  Fingers pointing at the other guys.

I don't have a direct solution but I do have a workaround that works every time.

Install the Disk Mount applet.  This is a built-in widget that simply has to be activated.  This applet displays on the top bar (Ubuntu mate 18.04 and beyond) the drives that are present and if a drive is clicked on, offers basic partition data.

Plug in your phone.  Two icons will appear.  One will do nothing.  The other allows one to to do various things including "mount"  Choose mount.  In a few seconds, the phone will be mounted and a file manager window will appear.

Proceed as if an automatic file manager window had opened when the phone is plugged into the USB port.

Note: Be SURE to un-mount the drive before disconnecting the phone.  Failing to do so leads to erratic behavior and generally requires a reboot.

Here is an alternative that I'd been using until I discovered the above method.

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/11/android-file-transfer-app-linux.

This is a clunky program but it does work.

Hope this helps.
John

Answer (score -1):

If you disabled the package with a disabler app search for MTP and enable it again. Takes a minute to turn back on, ask me how I know lol

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I'm not sure what exactly you're recommending. Therefore *I* recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)