Error message when connecting Android phone
When I connect my Android phone with my computer, I get this message.

How can I get rid of that message.

Once the phone is connected, set the connection mode as mass storage in the appropriate notification in the phone.
After that, you should be able to browse the phone's storage without any error.
You may have to install mtpfs with sudo apt install mtpfs

I found the answer here. https://askubuntu.com/questions/830714/mtp-connection-unable-to-mount-samsung-android-error-many-times-in-a-minute

@fixit7 Which answer worked?

I just had to install mtpfs
